# Problem with Google API authentication in Flutter

Tags: api, flutter

Just I have problem with authentication in Flutter. I have tried two last ways from documentation:
[Google news API Documentation][1]

My code:

````
  final String baseUrl = "https://newsapi.org/v2/";
  final String query = "top-headlines?country=gb&";
  final String authentication = ApiKey.apiKey;

  //For testing


  Future<List<Article>> getArticles() async {
    var response = await http.get(baseUrl + query, headers: <String, String>{
      "Authentication":authentication
    });
    List jsons = [];
    print(response.body);
  }

  Future<String> getSingleArticle(String url) async {
    var articleResponse = await http.get(url);
    String articleHTMLString = articleResponse.body;
    return articleHTMLString;

  }
}```



  [1]: https://newsapi.org/docs/authentication
````

Comment: I after running that I got:

> {"status":"error","code":"apiKeyMissing","message":"Your API key is missing. Append this to the URL with the apiKey param, or use the x-api-key HTTP header."}

Comment: When I'm using Postman for making request I get proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

you should make it like this way, probably will be fix.

```
  Future<List<Article>> getArticles() async {
    var response = await http.get(baseUrl + query, headers: <String, String>{
      "x-api-key":authentication // <-- On your comment.
    });
    List jsons = [];
    print(response.body);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. Unfortunately after application your code I get: {"message":"The request is invalid."}